# How to get dump of all image URLs from S3 bucket AWS?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to get a dump of all image URL's from one S3 bucket on AWS. How would I do this?  I have been trying below code, but I keep getting error `'s3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'generate_presigned_url'` and another issue is this code only fetches URL for only one image, if I pass the image name. I dont want to do that because I want images to change dynamically for my application.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

url = s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                Params={
                                    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
                                    'Key': 'upload/nocturnes.png',
                                },                                  
                                ExpiresIn=3600)
print url
```

EDIT:

This code gives me the list of keys in my bucket but not the URL of the keys.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket name')

for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    a= file.key
```

Comment: What is your question? Did you get it solved?

Comment: @Kannaiyan literally figured it out just now. Posting answer now.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the reason of generate  presigned URL, since object in S3 buckets is tied to specific region. Basically the presigned url path is fixed.  You just need one example presigned  url to learn the structure , then concatenate the rest.   But nothing to stop you if you have too much money to spare ;-)

Comment: @mootmoot do you think it would be a better approach to simply get a list of names store them locally and recreate the url within my application? why do you say it will cost a lot of money?

Comment: Presigned URL required one to make a GET request. A s3 GET will cost $0.004 / 10,000 requests.  If you have millions of files and keep pre-signed every time, you will notice the cost accumulate.  In fact, if you don't need to manipulate the object or get the attributes, you should use list_object_v2 than traverse the bucket using object.all

Comment: @mootmoot that makes alot of sense. I will definitely check out the list_object_v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)


for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    params = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': file.key}
    url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', params)
    print url
```

Comment: Please note that the purpose of a Pre-Signed URL is to provide time-limited access to a private object in Amazon S3. If your objects are publicly accessible, a Pre-Signed URL is not required. Also, your list of URLs will expire after 60 minutes (the default expiry time).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you for the explanation. Since I only want a dump of the URLs that I am storing in a list for later use, then it makes no difference if I use presigned_url versus not using presigned_url correct? if that is correct, then it really doesnt matter about the time limit since all the URL's are static. Hope the question makes sense

Comment: If the images are already publicly accessible, then you can simply construct a normal URL to access them, such as the one displayed in the S3 console when you click on an object. It will be similar to: `https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/key.jpg` (will vary by region)

Answer (score 0):

**For a bucket containing public objects:**

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)

res = []
for file in bucket.objects.all():
    url = f'https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{file.key}'
    res.append(url)
    print(url)
```